# constructor& self (void) what does this mean in a class

Tags: c++, constructor

I'm looking at C++ code, I'm stuck here at a constructor.

```
class sassy{    
    public:    
    sassy()    
    sassy& self(void) // what does this mean? what it does?    
};
```

Please clear my doubt.

Comment: What does it do? There's no implementation provided.

Comment: `void` as the parameter-list (of a function) is just another way to say that there are no parameters. `sassy` is the name of the type, and the constructor needs to have the same name. So `sassy& self(void);` is a member function named `self` taking no arguments and returning a reference to a `sassy`.

Comment: Hello and welcome to stackoverflow.com. Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist). You might also want to learn what a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) is.

Comment: That's not a constructor, it's a regular function. Presumably it returns `*this`, and is meant to provide some (questionable) Objective-C mimicry.

Comment: The code as pasted can't be correct. There's probably a `;` missing after the constructor. Also, `self` is *not* a constructor. And how can we know what it does without seeing its implementation?

Answer (score 1):

That construct declares a method without parameters that returns a reference to an instance of the same class. It's not a constructor - those must have a name same as the class itself.

It's hard to say what the intent is, it would depend on the actual implementation.

For example the implementation could just `return *this` and this was return the reference to the object itself.

Answer (score 1):

> what does this mean?

It's not a constructor; it's a member function. The function is called `self`, it returns a reference to an object of type `sassy`, and it takes no arguments - `(void)` means no arguments, just as `()` does, and some people like to use `(void)` to make their code harder to read.

> what it does?

Probably, it's implementation is `return *this;`, returning a reference to the object it's called on. This is completely pointless: if you're able to call the function, then you can get that reference without calling it.

Or perhaps it returns something else; in which case its name is misleading.

In either case, it's a weird function that has no reason to exist.

Answer (score 0):

It is merely a member function  which returns a reference to an instance of the current class; perhaps the same object. It's not a constructor. No idea what it's for.